# String-concatenation in bash leads to weird url

Tags: bash, curl, influxdb

when using the following command:
`url="http://localhost:8086/writedb=speedtest&u=${INFLUXDB_USERNAME}&p=${INFLUXDB_PASSWORD}"`
and then `echo "${url}"`

Before I use `source .env` to load my variables from the file:

```
INFLUXDB_USERNAME=admin
INFLUXDB_PASSWORD=admin
```

Leads to:

```
&p=adminocalhost:8086/write?db=speedtest&u=admin
curl: (3) Illegal characters found in URL
```

Comment: `source <(sed $'s/\r$//' .env)`

Comment: Why do I need to replace \r?

Comment: It looks like your .env file has [DOS/Windows line endings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39527571/are-shell-scripts-sensitive-to-encoding-and-line-endings), which cause all sorts of trouble unless they're converted to unix style.

Answer (score 0):

Solution: instead of `source .env`

```
source <(sed $'s/\r$//' .env)
```

Answer (score 0):

If your `.env` file was created in Windows you can convert it using

```
dos2unix .env
source .env
```